# The ISP keeps changing my modem DNS address

Tags: dns, modem

The ISP of mine in (Iran) keeps changing my DNS address on a daily basis, my modem goes on/off and then DNS changed to some other address:

```
5.200.200.200
217.218.127.127
```

How can I set the Google DNS and prevent the ISP from changing that, the modem is D-link DSL-2750U.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: @DavidPostill Then I will continue doing it manually... :(

Comment: welll, there is ISP equipment, and consumer equipment. the ISP can of course control the ISP equipment (modems, routers, etc) but the consumer's devices can be configured to use specific DNS servers. that is not a guarantee that the ISP cannot manipulate your traffic upstream of course, but if you are able to change the setting manually, and that works, then you can certianly change your individual devices to use a static DNS server address and ignore the DNS services provided on your modem/router (subject to your ISPs configuration).

Comment: I am surprised your internet connection still works when you set a manual IP address... with most ISPs, it will either stop working, or you'll be in conflict with someone else who uses the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: don't use the DNS provided by the modem. Most OS-es are able to force a static DNS server. Of course how it is done depends on the OS.

An alternative is to put your own SOHO-router between your network and the ISP's. You will be able to control your own SOHO router completely.